# place an image between other elements so that it scales to fit all screens while keeping aspect ration intact

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do that in my xml. Currently I'm doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawable_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/text" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_drawable_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_drawable_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_drawable_logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/credits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/credits" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my testing device I only get part of the `@drawable/logo`, the rest falls out of the screen as does the credit's text. I can of course adjust the weight until I have the desired outcome, but how can I make sure I will get the expected result on all devices?

What I want is `main_drawable_text` always matching the width of the screen (from margin to margin), `credits` always being on the bottom of the screen and `drawable_logo` been scaled to fit the free space between them, yet with the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand UI you want to design you don't need `LinearLayout` but only existing `RelativeLayout` and inside it you can place your element according to each others positions (with `android:layout_above`, `android:layout_below` and so on). To keep original ratio of your drawable use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.

Here is a layout which display (my interpretation of) what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawable_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/credits"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_drawable_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/credits"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```